# c# List<Tuple<string, string, int>> group by min max int

Tags: c#, list, tuples, max, min

i want to group by the following Tuple:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int>> tu = new List<Tuple<string, string, int>>();
tu.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>("a", "b", 201601));
tu.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>("a", "b", 201602));
tu.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>("a", "b", 201603));
tu.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>("c", "d", 201601));
tu.Add(new Tuple<string, string, int>("c", "d", 201602));
```

the result should look like this in a new Tuple:

```
//Item1, Item2, Min(Item2), Max(Item3)
List<Tuple<string, string, int, int>> newtu = new List<Tuple<string, string, int, int>>();

a,b,201601,201603
c,d,201601,201602
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: *I want to* => Ok, but what have to try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from t in tu
group t by new { t.Item1, t.Item2 } into g
select Tuple.Create(g.Key.Item1, g.Key.Item2, g.Min(t => t.Item3), g.Max(t => t.Item3));
```

Advise: do not use tuples in C#. ever

Comment: I'm intrigued why you would say to never use Tuples? Surely for private/internal members this is acceptable as you can maintain context?

Comment: what should I use then ?

Comment: @sr28 Tuples are good, e.g. in Python. But C# tuples are not self-describing data structures - they have ugly Item1, Item2, Item3 properties which tell nothing about data stored there. Same with tuples creation - parameters don't have names and it's easy to put value in wrong position. If you want to make your code less clean and readable, then tuples are good :) otherwise I would suggest to use anonymous object or create nice self-descriptive class.

Comment: Tuples can be used to get a type with a short lifetime and method context or to communicate between two methods where the one that returns the tuple should be private.

Comment: @TimSchmelter why not use anonymous objects in method context?

Comment: Anyway, I have seen several times code with Tuples. It's a big pain to understand what is stored there. And it's impossible to guess if you don't know exact context. Algorithm is following - you go inside method which returns tuple and check what is stored in Items, then return to your code and use it. Same with creating tuple. You should remember exactly what to put at which position. Otherwise receiver of tuple will get wrong data. I'm pretty average person which can hold around 7 items in memory. Holding positions of data in tuple reduces my memory dramatically :)

Comment: And as an example, just look at the code in this answer, with it's meaningless `Item1`, `Item2` and `Item3` - it's awkward to read, even in that tiny snippet.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: it's meaningless to you but maybe not for OP. Tuples can be abused without doubt. But that doesn't mean that they are always bad. They just should be used very seldom and only in one logical operation. Don't expose tuples to outside. They are a convenient way to get a type with few similar properties, all the more if you need an auto implemented `Equals`+`GetHashCode` and if you need to pass this to a related method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter This tuple is going into a list, which in my opinion is bad, even if it's local to a class. It's so totally quick to write a little class with named properties that to not do so is simply lazy. And I personally write code that other people can read too (including my future self).

Comment: @MatthewWatson nice catch. And imagine that you are working with method which returns this list of `Tuple<string, string, int, int>`. You should go to that method, then see this LINQ query, read it and understand that Item3 is minimum value of something. That's just counter-productive. I would prefer to get some data type like `FileDownloadsStats { ServerName, FileName, MinDownloadsPerDay, MaxDownloadsPerDay }` with this data structure I don't need to investigate method and LINQ query. Also it's much harder to miss something when you are creating these objects

Comment: Anyway, with any luck we'll get [C# language support for tuples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/347) in C# 7 which should cover the most common (and valid) uses for Tuples.

Answer (score 2):

Group by an anonymous type, then use `Min` + `Max` on the groups:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, int, int>> newtu = tu
    .GroupBy(t => new { t1 = t.Item1, t2 = t.Item2 })
    .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key.t1, g.Key.t2, g.Min(t => t.Item3), g.Max(t => t.Item3)))
    .ToList();
```